# unexpected character '?' express

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, babeljs

When I run my `server.js` file I get a syntax error with something along the lines like the following:

> Unexpected character `?`  in the file `@babel\core\lib\transformation\normalize-file.js:209`

When I try to execute my `server.js` with following code:

```
import path from 'path';
import express from 'express';

var app = express();
var port = 3000;
​
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

But its fine if I run it with following code:

```
import http from 'http';

http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

There seems to be an issue with express and babel maybe?

I'll add the `package.json` and the `.babelrc` below:

**`package.json`:**

```
{
  "name": "counter",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.1",
    "@babel/node": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "^2.1.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.4",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^16.5.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.1",
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.6.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "redux": "^3.5.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --exec babel-node server\\server.js ",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "test": "react-scripts test"
  }
}
```

**`.babelrc`:**

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-react","env"],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import","dynamic-import-node"]
}
```

Comment: Instead of es6 import can you try using conventional require statements for path and express

Comment: yes but in the future i would like to use import statements like this: import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

Comment: That’s alright I’m just trying to figure out whether in your node file does  using require makes it functional without syntax error @Crappapel edna

Comment: import seems to work fine in the second example code ( import http from 'http';) i provided. so i think it might not be the issue